# Why VTOR in stm32 is set `SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET` instead `SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE + VECT_TAB_OFFSET`

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, bootloader, cortex-m

Why do we use OR instead ADD in this code?

```
#ifdef VECT_TAB_SRAM
  SCB->VTOR = SRAM_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal SRAM */
#else
  SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */
#endif
```

I am not able to understand why this works. Based on my understanding, it should be ADD, but it is not like that. This means I am missing something.

https://github.com/niekiran/BootloaderProjectSTM32/blob/2a6d8fa6a461f4a9e0e8a81b41c34fc60be1ec0c/SourceCode/BOOTLOADER/KEIL/Nucleo-F446RE/bootloader_STM32F446xx/Src/system_stm32f4xx.c#L198-L202

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the definitions of `SRAM_BASE`, `FLASH_BASE`, and `VECT_TAB_OFFSET`. -- What don't you understand, the bitwise OR operator? If you want to know the _reason_ for choosing this operator, you need to ask the authors of that source code. Depending on the specific values of the base addresses and the offset, the result is the same as with a sum.